# Using Redis protocol over Ignite

Tags: redis, ignite

We are kind of evaluating the cons and pros between Ignite and Redis.

On official documents, it is said Ignite is partially Redis compliant. With that said, some commands / function come with limitations on the documents. Are there other unsupported features / known issues that Ignite-Redis does not clarify on the document?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands listed on the [docs page](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/redis) should work.

You can also check out [known issues that mention Redis](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20IGNITE%20AND%20text%20~%20redis%20and%20status%20not%20in%20(closed%2C%20resolved)).

If you find that something else doesn't work, please report it to user@ignite.apache.org.